# Retina Display Coordinates in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, retina

Making masking rectangle for the pattern in Illustrator I should insert the central coordinates of shapes in 4 angles of the pattern and I have coordinates numbers like 45.401px, however when I insert this number only 45.4 px is saved and in resultant Divide Objects Below command for pattern I get non perfect margins and thus the pattern does not match.

How can I solve the issue? Align to pixel grid is switched off....

look at the pic

[image]

upd I follow [this](http://www.natulrich.com/ru/lessons/lessons15.php) tutorial, so don't be critical about logics etc. Also, pay attention to this sentence: when I take a number like 34.301 px and insert it as coordinate to Transform item and reopen Transform - I see that coordinate as 34.3 and not 34.301.

Comment: Not sure I entirely follow you, but you should never have fractional px when designing for screen. For retina, you'll want to create the image twice the normal size.

Comment: look at the picture in the update. The angle element has 2 coordinated for the center - I take these x;y and insert to rectangle coordinates for Dividing the pattern. Unfortunately, I the numbers are not accepted as I insert them...

Comment: So you're trying to be pixel precise but not use whole pixels? Your logic is terribly flawed I fear.

Comment: FYI for that pattern you only need 5 black objects (http://i.stack.imgur.com/xhsfo.png). I also don't understand *why* you feel you need to use Pathfinder for anything.

Comment: @scott actually, I think you can get away with 3. :)

Comment: Please, follow the link in the update of the question. You don't need to understand the language there - pictures are enough.

Comment: @Scott, convert your 2 last comments to answer. I've repeated the tutorial with Points changing the pattern shapes coordinates to points and the pattern now gives a perfect seamless picture. Also, your last comment contains very important information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although I'm unable to read it, based on the images, the tutorial you linked to may not be the best tutorial to follow. There are much more efficient ways to create seamless patterns in Illustrator. This is *especially* true if you are using Illustrator CS6 or newer with the Pattern Editor feature.

I would happily link to better tutorials, but I doubt I could find anything in the language you need. However, I would suggest you find another tutorial on creating seamless patterns in Illustrator. If you have Illustrator CS6+ look for Pattern Editor tutorials.

Also note, the tutorial at your link is using **points** as a unit and **NOT** pixels. There is a difference in how the application sees pixels vs points.

For the record, Illustrator *does* round numbers if you have more than two after a decimal point. According to the developers, accurate measurements are retained for the objects and it's merely the dialog fields which show rounding. I'm not entirely convinced that is the case. However, I don't think I've ever created anything that required accuracy to a thousandth of a point either.

Generally a hundredth of a point is as small as I ever need. A thousandth of a point difference is certainly nothing a monitor or human eye could ever see. So, unless you are doing absolute precision work for laser cutting or some other fabrication, I'd suggest you not concern yourself with anything more than a hundredth of a point in general.

No monitor I'm aware of could ever show a partial pixel, and really can't show a partial point in many instances (when viewing at 100%). Commercial presses generally can't hold lines below .25pt in weight. Some can, but it's best to not go smaller than .25pt for printing. So, X.001 is much more precise that you probably need.

Comment: thanks for the answer, the issue solved for now (changing px to pt) . I will looking for a better tutorial. accepted